# Will using unicode chars in my password increase security?

Tags: passwords, brute-force

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do non-keyboard characters make my password less susceptible to brute forcing?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4632/do-non-keyboard-characters-make-my-password-less-susceptible-to-brute-forcing)

Bruteforce tries cracking the hash with every possible combination of letters.

Then, If I'll use an special Unicode char, as ♥ or ¿, will it increase my security?

I'm talking about NTLM passwords.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

In the sense you are increasing the entropy of your password, making it harder to perform bruteforce attacks against.

I am from a country where we use non-english letters. This allowed me to use characters not common used in a charset by a brute-force applications, but I effectivly locked myself out of my webmail when I used a computer without my regional keyboard settings.

Edit:

Googling NTLM + unicode shows that there is support for unicode as NTLM password.

Comment: i google that but i guess if you add one other phrase the googling is better that just __NTLM + unicode__