# Chinese or "pinyin" wordlists for dictionary attacks

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, dictionary

Background:

I am currently trying to crack a salted md5 hash which I have recovered from an embedded device running busybox and manufactured in china.

I have tried john the ripper using all of the wordlists I could find in Kali.

I have tried cloudcracker and that returned no results.

I am currently brute-forcing on a machine with several GPUS using oclHashcat but haven't got anything back yet.

I have a serial console on the device which is in English. I have a low privileged account with the username jdoe and no password. I have handed this to someone who is much better at Linux privesc than I am.

I want to ensure that the device does not have a noddy password in Chinese. I.e. whatever the equivalent of "password" "hello" "letmein" etc. would be if you were a electronics factory in Shenzhen.

I am aware that there are multiple Chinese dialects but would be interested in wordlists from any of them as it would be worth a try anyway and they may be useful on similar devices.

---

TLDR: I have tried Google and had difficulty finding Chinese or "pinyin" wordlists suitable for dictionary attacks. I have searched this site and found some good sources for wordlists which I will probably try next but they are mainly in English and I have not seen any in Chinese.

Does anyone know of a good source for them?

---

Edit: Further searching has found me this http://www.backtrack-linux.org/forums/showthread.php?t=27764 which I will try. I am unsure if that will provide decent coverage for my purposes though.

---

### Edit 2:

I have posted an ascii seed symbol wordlist generated from the top answer below at http://pastebin.com/aHrnZF57

This should be able to be used to generate wordlists of your desired length by using the "crunch" wordlist generator or your favourite alternative tool.

### For example:

Save the raw pastebin data as seed.txt in your home directory then invoke:

`crunch MIN MAX -q ~\seed.txt -o myOutputWordlist.txt`

The same can be done by substituting my seed list with some of those available from the backtrack-linux forums thread linked above.

Hope this helps anyone with this problem - Happy bruteforcing :)

Comment: There's only a small amount of pinyin possibilities, if you really wanted to you could just look up initials and finals and combine them and you'll have the full... what?... 400 possible combinations?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Chinese (Mandarin) is a very phonologically restrictive language with a limited amount of possible syllables. Hence, you can make a table consisting of every possible syllable in the Chinese language as exemplified here:

```
        a       ai      au      an      aŋ      e       ə       əi      əu      ən      əŋ      i       ia      iai     iau     ian     iaŋ     ie      iə      iəu     iən     iəŋ     io      iu      iuan    iuə     iun     iuəŋ    aɻ      o       u       ua      uai     uan     uaŋ     uə      uəi     uən     uəŋ     m       n       ŋ      
        a       ai      ao      an      ang     ê       e       ei      ou      en      eng     yi      ya      yai     yao     yan     yang    yê      ye      you     yin     ying    yo      yu      yuan    yue     yun     yong    er      o       wu      wa      wai     wan     wang    wo      wei     wun     weng    m       n       ng     
p       ba      bai     bao     ban     bang            bo      bei             ben     beng    bi                      biao    bian    biang           bie     biu     bin     bing                                                                    bu                                                                                             
pʰ      pa      pai     pao     pan     pang            po      pei     pou     pen     peng    pi                      piao    pian                    pie     piu     pin     ping                                                                    pu                                                                                             
m       ma      mai     mao     man     mang            mo      mei     mou     men     meng    mi                      miao    mian                    mie     miu     min     ming                                                                    mu                                                                                             
f       fa                      fan     fang            fo      fei     fou     fen     feng                                                                                                                                                            fu                                                                                             
t       da      dai     dao     dan     dang            de      dei     dou     den     deng    di                      diao    dian                    die     diu             ding                                                                    du                      duan            duo     dui     dun     dong                           
tʰ      ta      tai     tao     tan     tang            te              tou             teng    ti                      tiao    tian                    tie     tiu             ting                                                                    tu                      tuan            tuo     tui     tun     tong                           
n       na      nai     nao     nan     nang            ne      nei     nou     nen     neng    ni                      niao    nian    niang           nie     niu     nin     ning            nü              nüe                                     nu                      nuan            nuo                     nong                           
l       la      lai     lao     lan     lang            le      lei     lou             leng    li      lia             liao    lian    liang           lie     liu     lin     ling            lü              lüe                             lo      lu                      luan            luo             lun     long                           
ts      za      zai     zao     zan     zang            ze      zei     zou     zen     zeng    zi                                                                                                                                                      zu                      zuan            zuo     zui     zun     zong                           
tsʰ     ca      cai     cao     can     cang            ce              cou     cen     ceng    ci                                                                                                                                                      cu                      cuan            cuo     cui     cun     cong                           
s       sa      sai     sao     san     sang            se              sou     sen     seng    si                                                                                                                                                      su                      suan            suo     sui     sun     song                           
tʂ      zha     zhai    zhao    zhan    zhang           zhe     zhei    zhou    zhen    zheng   zhi                                                                                                                                                     zhu     zhua    zhuai   zhuan   zhuang  zhuo    zhui    zhun    zhong                          
tʂʰ     cha     chai    chao    chan    chang           che             chou    chen    cheng   chi                                                                                                                                                     chu     chua    chuai   chuan   chuang  chuo    chui    chun    chong                          
ʂ       sha     shai    shao    shan    shang           she     shei    shou    shen    sheng   shi                                                                                                                                                     shu     shua    shuai   shuan   shuang  shuo    shui    shun                                   
ɻ                       rao     ran     rang            re              rou     ren     reng    ri                                                                                                                                                      ru      rua             ruan            ruo     rui     run     rong                           
tɕ                                                                                              ji      jia             jiao    jian    jiang           jie     jiu     jin     jing            ju      juan    jue     jun     jiong                                                                                                                  
tɕʰ                                                                                             qi      qia             qiao    qian    qiang           qie     qiu     qin     qing            qu      quan    que     qun     qiong                                                                                                                  
ɕ                                                                                               xi      xia             xiao    xian    xiang           xie     xiu     xin     xing            xu      xuan    xue     xun     xiong                                                                                                                  
k       ga      gai     gao     gan     gang            ge      gei     gou     gen     geng                                                                                                                                                            gu      gua     guai    guan    guang   guo     gui     gun     gong                           
kʰ      ka      kai     kao     kan     kang            ke      kei     kou     ken     keng                                                                                                                                                            ku      kua     kuai    kuan    kuang   kuo     kui     kun     kong                           
x       ha      hai     hao     han     hang            he      hei     hou     hen     heng                                                                                                                                                            hu      hua     huai    huan    huang   huo     hui     hun     hong
```

The first row are the column headings and the first column are the row headings. Thus, you can ignore the first row and column as they were for my aid in learning Mandarin pronounciation.

You may want to substitute `ü` with `v` as that is how it is inputted on a keyboard since no pinyin syllable uses `v`. (It’s quite a bit more accessible than typing an accented character.)

Many syllables are not used and their positions are, thus, empty in the table giving a total of 410 possible syllables. Furthermore, there are 5 tones (beginning with 0) in the Mandarin Chinese language denoted by numbers, so a password could be something like `gao1mi4`. Counting the tones, there are 2050 possible syllables. With Chinese words being typically 1 to 3 syllables long, it's a real possibility that you could break a Pinyin-based password in  less than 8,615,125,000 attempts using random combinations of syllables and tones without the aid of a word list.

Comment: Awesome - thanks. Will try and build a list from this and possibly use markov chaining to see if I can improve it.
Will upvote when I have the rep and post my list as a comment to my question.

Comment: If I may add some more hints, typing Pinyin in an IME does not require the use of the `SHIFT` or `CAPS LOCK` keys. You might want to start with all lowercase. I can also see a Chinese user will probably omit the tone number altogether. The Chinese military was known to send messages in pinyin without the tones because they could be understood without the tones anyway.

Comment: I've added a textual table to replace the graphic one I took from Pinyin.info. This one can be copied into other software.

If you want a challenge, there are 4 standardized vocabulary lists from the Taiwanese government. Basically, the words on that list are the ones people will most likely use. They are listed with the Pinyin, although they use tone marks and not tone numbers.

http://www.sc-top.org.tw/download/800Words_Beginners.pdf
http://www.sc-top.org.tw/download/8000_Basic.pdf
http://www.sc-top.org.tw/download/8000_Intermediate.pdf
http://www.sc-top.org.tw/download/8000_Advanced.pdf